# Is php's socket_select() guaranteed to detect all client socket disconnections?

Tags: php, sockets

Is php's [socket_select()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) method guaranteed to detect all client socket disconnections?

I've seen a few code examples that use the read array in php's socket_select() method to detect client socket disconnection, such as this one:
[How to detect client disconnection on PHP socket listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996215/how-to-detect-client-disconnection-on-php-socket-listener)

But does it return FALSE for ALL client socket disconnection? If there are any exceptions, what are they?

Comment: Why do you expect exceptions from that?

Comment: @hek2mgl
It's not a question of whether I do or don't expect exceptions.  It's a question of _should I_ expect exceptions?

Comment: No, you would not need to expect exceptions. Should I really answer that?!

Comment: @hek2mgl
I would be very happy if are correct.  But can you support your answer to backup your claim?

Comment: The question is what do you mean with `ALL`. Actually all TCP sockets behave the same (speaking TCP). There is only `ONE` way to close the connection: send a `FIN` paket. This is what actually will be handled by `socket_select()`

Comment: @hek2mgl By all I mean both graceful and ungraceful disconnections.  For example, a user's device may explode (or more realistically, simply shut off due to a power cord being pulled or running out of battery).

Comment: No you can't handle that without help from the kernel. If the client explodes or just a power outage happens on client side it will not be able to send the FIN paket anymore. In this case the connection stays open forever. For this purpose the Linux Kernel supports so called `tcp-keepalives`.. Check this: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html .. However some higher level protocols transported over TCP have their on keep-alive (or call it heartbeat) features.

Comment: I can create an answer later.. Need to be AFK for a while..

Comment: @hek2mgl What you're saying makes sense.  A device can't possibly send a FIN packet if it gets disconnected unexpectedly (like a cat tripping over your ethernet cable). And okay that would be cool. I'd like to see if other people agree/disagree with you.

Comment: Btw, I was wrong when saying that the connection can be only closed by `FIN`. `RST` is also possible. Probably there are even more ways? I don't expect that but I'm not the super-tcp-expert. However I would say socket_select() would be aware of that since the underlying kernel handles low level TCP. I expect the kernels to implement TCP correctly, but hey! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;TR**

You need to send TCP pakets containing data of zero length periodically and wait for the `ACK` from client to make sure it isn't physically disconnected. Otherwise `socket_select()` will assume the connection is still open if a a client gets physically disconnected. On Linux the kernel can help - it is called [`TCP keep-alives`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html)

---

**Explanation**

The question is what do you mean with `ALL` types of client  disconnections. In comments you stated that you have concerns about ungraceful client disconnects. What would happen if a power outage happens on client?

First a short sentence about graceful client disconnections. In TCP there are two ways how a client could close the connection: sending a `FIN` packet to the server or sending an `RST` packet. (The latter will unlikely happen on client side). `socket_select()` is aware of these both ways how a disconnect could happen gracefully.

If the client gets physically disconnected while the connection is open it is not able to send a `FIN` or `RST` packet anymore. This could happen because of many reasons like a power outage, a defect cable, a defect switch etc...

In such a case the connection would stay open forever on server side, since TCP does not implement a timeout meaning it does not require that packets will be sent. After successful connect the connection stays open unless a `FIN` or `RST` packet is received.

So there is no chance how to detect broken connections? No, there is still a way how to detect those. The concept is called `TCP keep-alive` packets.

`TCP keep-alives` are based on a feature of the TCP protocol: When you send data in TCP the receiver responds with an `ACK` packet signalling that the packet where received successfully. `TCP keep-alive` packets are packets containing data of zero length, just meant to trigger an `ACK` packet on the client. Note that the client does not need to implement `keep-alives`. It is plain `TCP`.

On Linux, the kernel can help to send those `keep-alives`. If no data was received on a socket in a given (configurable) timeout the kernel will send those zero length packets and close the socket if no `ACK` is received withing a configurable amount of time. There is also a configurable retry interval. If the kernel closes the socket, `socket_select()` would be aware of that.

Learn how to configure `TCP keep-alives` on Linux: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

Unfortunately I have no experience with `TCP keep-alives` on other operating systems but I guess the also support something like that.

Comment: are there any examples how to use the "exception" parameter for php socket_select ?